# APT ANT task fails in eclipse but works from shell

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, javac, apt

I have a ant `javac` task which is supposed to run some annotation processor. It works fine when run from a batch file, but fails with

Error running javac.exe compiler

when started from eclipse. Normal compiling `javac` tasks work just fine.

I guess ant started from eclipse uses some different compiler?
How do I change it to the normal compiler? Or make it work in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually because of a [missing `tool.jar`](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools/msg61246.html)

> You are missing a `tools.jar` on the runtime classpath of Ant used in the Eclipse integration.
>   If you start Eclipse with a JDK install (using the `-vm` argument), `tools.jar` will be added automatically.
>   Otherwise, you can add it yourself using `Window>Preferences>Ant>Runtime>Classpath`. (see also [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg18268.html))

[image: http://web.archive.org/web/20130109065622/http://img246.i_mageshack.us/img246/9712/eclipseantruntime.png]

Note: a `fork="true"` can [also be problematic](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg13959.html).

Comment: Simply removing the fork attribute from my build.xml task worked for me.